# Deadlock detection with JVMTI

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, jvmti

I wonder whether it is possible to detect deadlocks dynamically in Java by using the JVMTI. There are two events indicating actions on monitors using the synchronized statement:

**Monitor Contended Enter**

> Sent when a thread is attempting to enter a Java programming language monitor **already acquired** by another thread.

**Monitor Contended Entered**

> Sent when a thread enters a Java programming language monitor **after waiting for it to be released** by another thread.

This means, with JVMTI I can only see those monitors which are already locked. I wanted to reconstruct a wait-for graph, but without events indicating me, that a lock was acquired which is **not** held by any thread. This is impossible.

Are there alternatives? The SIGQUIT command on Unix allows a thread dump which displays the deadlocks, it seems like this is not possible within JVMTI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get this information via JMX.

Try

```
ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().findMonitorDeadlockedThreads();
```

Comment: Yes, but this would be using a java agent, not a native agent.

Comment: You can call Java code from native code. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: I didn't think native agents used byte code, I thought they were written in C.

Comment: They are, so can I use the JNI to make calls to Java methods like descriped here? http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html

Comment: Correct, anything you can do in a Java agent, you can do in a native agent and visa versa with JNI. ;) On bizarre example is File.length() which is a native method, but the first thing it does is convert the character encoding of the file name in Java via JNI. :P